# Invalid mapping expression parameter specified

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am trying to write a Swagger config for the AWS API Gateway deployment, and came up with this for a sample (mostly copied from the documentation):

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "desc",
    "title": "TestAPI",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "test",
            "headers": {
              "Content-type": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
          "type" : "aws",
          "uri" : "[REDACTED]",
          "credentials" : "[REDACTED]",
          "httpMethod" : "POST",
          "requestTemplates" : {
            "application/json" : "#set ($root=$input.path('$')) { \"stage\": \"$root.name\", \"user-id\": \"$root.key\" }"
          },
          "requestParameters" : {
            "integration.request.querystring.stage" : "method.request.querystring.version",
            "integration.request.querystring.provider" : "method.request.querystring.vendor"
          },
          "responses" : {
            "2\\d{2}" : {
              "statusCode" : "200",
              "responseParameters" : {
                "method.response.header.requestId" : "integration.response.header.cid"
              },
              "responseTemplates" : {
                "application/json" : "#set ($root=$input.path('$')) { \"stage\": \"$root.name\", \"user-id\": \"$root.key\" }"
              }
            },
            "302" : {
              "statusCode" : "302",
              "responseParameters" : {
                "method.response.header.Location" : "integration.response.body.redirect.url"
              }
            },
            "default" : {
              "statusCode" : "400",
              "responseParameters" : {
                "method.response.header.test-method-response-header" : "'static value'"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is that

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api --body 'file://deploy/api.json' --region eu-west-1
```

Outputs the following:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ImportRestApi operation: Errors found during import:
    Unable to put integration on 'GET' for resource at path '/': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.request.querystring.version]
```

That part is taken directly from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html), so this is really confusing to me. Any ideas what to do? Documentation seems lacking in many ways, so it is hard to solve many problems with it.

Comment: Please mark the answer if it helps solve the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried defining `version` and `vendor` as parameters to the method?

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "desc",
    "title": "TestAPI",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters" : [
            {
                "name" : "version",
                "in" : "query",
                "required" : true,
                "type" : "string"
                "description" : "The version requested"
            },          
            {
                "name" : "vendor",
                "in" : "query",
                "required" : true,
                "type" : "string"
                "description" : "The vendor being queried"
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "test",
            "headers": {
              "Content-type": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
          "type" : "aws",
          "uri" : "[REDACTED]",
          "credentials" : "[REDACTED]",
          "httpMethod" : "POST",
          "requestTemplates" : {
            "application/json" : "#set ($root=$input.path('$')) { \"stage\": \"$root.name\", \"user-id\": \"$root.key\" }"
          },
          "requestParameters" : {
            "integration.request.querystring.stage" : "method.request.querystring.version",
            "integration.request.querystring.provider" : "method.request.querystring.vendor"
          },
          "responses" : {
            "2\\d{2}" : {
              "statusCode" : "200",
              "responseParameters" : {
                "method.response.header.requestId" : "integration.response.header.cid"
              },
              "responseTemplates" : {
                "application/json" : "#set ($root=$input.path('$')) { \"stage\": \"$root.name\", \"user-id\": \"$root.key\" }"
              }
            },
            "302" : {
              "statusCode" : "302",
              "responseParameters" : {
                "method.response.header.Location" : "integration.response.body.redirect.url"
              }
            },
            "default" : {
              "statusCode" : "400",
              "responseParameters" : {
                "method.response.header.test-method-response-header" : "'static value'"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

API Gateway requires method request parameters to be [defined before being referenced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-requestParameters.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer: it has saved my day! :) The point I got stuck on was in the "responses" under "paths", the mapping must be "headerS" rather than "header" like it is under "responseParameters" (method.response.header.xxx). Sheesh, I wish there were examples with Swagger OpenAPI and CloudFormation together

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'm not working with Swagger but I was trying to set up an API Gateway Method for an HTTP proxy with CloudFormation, and it complained with the same error - explicitly defining the RequestParameters (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-requestparameters) solved the issue.